# Syntax Error when passing non-existing variable from PHP into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling

I have the following code that passes a variable (EmployeeID) from PHP into JavaScript:

```
EmployeeID= <?php echo "$EmployeeID"?>;
```

The issue is that the variable EmployeeID in PHP might not exist, in which case, after I run the JavaScript code,  I receive an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

When I look into the Source Code in Dev Tools I can see this:

```
EmployeeID = ;
```

What would be the best way to handle this error? I tried

```
if (EmployeeID == null){
    EmployeeID = "0"; //0 - stands for generic variable in case if EmployeeID doesn't exist
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This php code outputs either `$EmployeeID` value or `0`, so your js var holds 0 when `$EmployeeID` has falsy value:

```
var EmployeeID = <?php echo $EmployeeID ? $EmployeeID : 0 ?>;
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Comment: May be it is better to check `isset($EmloyeeID)` if variable might not exist

Comment: @VitalijsG. indeed it maybe. But I just showed an example how to __always__ output something. Even `??` operator can be used, which eliminates the need for `isset`.

Comment: Yeah I would have gone with null coalesce. DRY and all that, and will avoid undefined variable notices in the log file in case it's not set.

Answer (score 1):

As the first answer states, a shothanded if is a great solution for this case

```
<?php echo $EmployeeID ? $EmployeeID : 0 ?>
```

But in this case the output will be `0` if `$EmployeeID == 0, null, false, ''`, for this case i strongly recomment you to use the method ´isset()´, as the variable may not be declared (for example if an employeeID is actually 0)

```
<?php 
  if(isset($EmployeeID)){
       // Do something here
  } else {
       // whatever u need
  }
```

For a better refference about [**php-isset**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

So the other answers will likely work fine for what I'm assuming is a numeric value, but in case you have a text value, you'll want to ensure it's properly escaped for JavaScript. `json_encode()` is perfect for this. I'd do something like this:

```
EmployeeID= <?= json_encode($EmployeeID ?? null) ?>;
```

This will ensure that any text is properly escaped, and the [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) gives you a default without triggering notices about undefined variables in case the variable doesn't have a value.